# Optimizing capture lists

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, closures

Is there such a thing? Is there any difference between the two below? Is one more "correct" than the other?

All objects are properties of `self` (let's say a view controller) and have the same lifetime as `self`. We can introduce an object with a shorter lifetime than `self`, which would be `weak`, but the same question applies.

```
objectOne.doSomething { [unowned self] in
    self.objectTwo.finish()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    // self.someDelegate?.didFinishSomething()
}
```

vs

```
objectOne.doSomething { 
    [unowned objectTwo = self.objectTwo,
    unowned tableView = self.tableView
    // weak someDelegate = self.delegate
    ] in
    objectTwo.finish()
    tableView.reloadData()
    // someDelegate?.didFinishSomething()
}
```

Apple has this example in [their docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56):

```
lazy var someClosure: () -> String = {
    [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] in
    // closure body goes here

    delegate?.doSomething()
}
```

In this case, `delegate` can have a shorter lifetime than `self`, but why not use it like this?

```
lazy var someClosure: () -> String = { 
    [unowned self] in
    // closure body goes here

    self.delegate?.doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an important difference. In the case of the Apple docs, the code alternative you presented:

```
lazy var someClosure: () -> String = { 
    [unowned self] in
    // closure body goes here

    self.delegate?.doSomething()
}
```

will look up the *current* `delegate` on `self` when the closure runs.

In the Apple example version:

```
lazy var someClosure: () -> String = {
    [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] in
    // closure body goes here

    delegate?.doSomething()
}
```

the weak `delegate` var in the capture list is *copying* the `delegate` pointer on `self` that exists at the time of closure *declaration*, not execution. So if the value of `self.delegate` changes after the closure is declared and is different at the time the closure runs, the Apple version of the closure will have a nil delegate (assumedly since the reference to the old delegate was weak) and do nothing.

So as a general rule, copying values or references in capture lists (`[someIdentifier = someProperty]`) is how to use the values or references as they exist at the moment the closure is defined. Whereas declaring weak or unowned self in the capture list (`[weak self]`) and then accessing properties on that weak reference (`{ self?.someProperty }`) will get the values of the properties as they exist when the closure is *executed*.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you! This should be, then, an underlying reason for the behaviour in my answer: the `lazy` init is triggered when the closure is declared, combined with the fact that it's on another thread than other triggers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems that `[unowned objectOne = self.objectOne]` might cause is with `lazy var UIViews` and racing conditions: if you aren't careful and the `lazy` init gets called from different threads, two instances might end up being created. Furthermore, if your `superview.addSubview(objectOne)` call is in the `lazy` init, both instances will be added to the `superview`, and `objectOne` will point to one of the two instances.